# What exactly marks an Angular2 reactive FormControl as dirty beside user interaction?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, dirty-checking

This is a question to gain a deeper understanding of Angular Reactive Forms.

We're about to create a lot complex components with lots of FormControl objects in each dialog. Therfor many things are set dynamically at runtime for those FormControl objects:

- data from model (obvious)
- validation rules (via `control.setValidators(valArray)`)
- enablement/diablement (e.g. via `control.disable()`)

Code examples are to large to show here.

**The problem is**: after setting all components to new values, validations and enablement **and** a final `this.formGoup.marktAsPristine()` some fields are still or again **dirty**

One thing is, that we still have some Angular typical concurrency topics to solve. So it's - in the moment - more than likely that after that `this.formGoup.marktAsPristine()` some concurrent activities are still running. But for my understanding of Angular:

**What actions can set a FormControl again to dirty, if no user interaction took place so far?**

Documentation and my quite fat Angular book could not explain it to me.

Comment: To play around, I created a stackblitz example, that shows no reason, why a FormControl gets dirty without user interaction: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-form-control-flags). Stackblitz is Angular 10, we use still Angular 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the angular docs

> A control is dirty if the user has changed the value in the UI.

`FormControls` don't update themselves without some interaction either from the user, or the code is somehow doing this. i.e. via `markAsDirty()`

Do keep in mind that the 'dirty' property, like the `invalid` property will bubble up. so if you are nesting `FormGroup` or `FormArray`, you may be seeing values at the top level that are reflective of nesting.

The fact that you mention concurrency makes me question if you are using the `{ emitEvent: false }` option when setting the values of your control programmatically. i.e. when using `patchValue`

similarly making sure to use `onlySelf` where appropriate to reduce the amount of "bubbling up" that occurs.

Comment: Thx @Edward, {emitEvent:false} is a good point. The bubbleing of 'dirty' from FormControl to FormGroup I'm aware of. Only some FomrControls inside FormGroup are dirty.

Comment: Thx @Edward, it was the missing of { emitEvent: false } at a certain position in code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pass the options with {onlySelf: false}? Otherwise it will only mark that abstractcontrol as pristine.

Comment: I called markAsPristine() on the whole FormGroup after setting all the new values

Comment: `markAsPristine(opts: { onlySelf?: boolean; } = {}): void`

Without that flag you will only mark the current AbstractControl as pristine.

see: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markaspristine